# Error opening ListView item

Tags: android, android-listview

I have created database which creates new item in listview. ListView contains:

1)TextView

2)CheckBox

3)TableRow

When I ask to create only TextView code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <TextView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/text1" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="10dip"/>
```

Then I can open ListView item. But when I ask to create all 3 things code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="4.54" >

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/check"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:focusable="false"/>

     <TextView 
    android:id="@+id/text1" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="10dip"/>

    </TableRow>

</LinearLayout>
```

I am able to open the ListItem when I click in CheckBox and TextView area. I can not open it with whole row. What have I missed, how can I open ListItem when I click to row?

Comment: how can I open ListItem when I click to row? elaborate pls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okei then I found a solution sorry for bothering. If you want an answer here it is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">



        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/check"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:focusable="false"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/check"
            android:padding="10dip"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```